# How can .mp3, .mp4 files be transfered from a computer to a Windows 10 phone?

Tags: windows-10, windows-phone

I have a Nokia Lumia Windows phone. I've found that though you can attach the device to a linux machine via the USB data cable, once you transfer music files to the phone the do not populate in the music player.

What's the best workaround for this?

Comment: If you managed to write your files into the phone, then it's not a Ubuntu 'problem'. It's a Windows 'problem' or a music player 'problem'. You should ask them. Or maybe look for a refresh-music-database button in your music player.

Answer (score 0):

Qlix handles this, and handles it well.

`apt-get install qlix`

Answer (score 0):

1. Disconnect your phone from the computer.
2. Close the Music App if open.
3. Start the Music App and it will refresh the changes made.